# Passive form of verb + preposition + gerund

Tags: passive-voice

What would the passive form of this sentence be?

> - Brian is working hard on improving his vocabulary.
> - Brian's vocabulary is being worked hard on improving?

Comment: Hello user259423! Welcome to EL&U please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). Please consider whether your question might be better suited for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider something like:

> Improvements to Brian's vocabulary are being worked on.

---

Incorporating the use of **hard** in your original sentence would require some kind of additional rephrasing. Depending on how it's interpreted, something like the following might work:

> Improvements to Brian's vocabulary are being diligently worked on.

Comment: "Improving his vocabulary is being worked on, hard, by Brian."